# find_library() cannot find basic shared library MacOS Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am learning to make my own libraries and to begin, I wanted to link a basic working example to see how the process is done. However, CMake find_library() is not finding my library file correctly.

So I created a simple project and built libmy_lib.dylib. Then I created another project to link to libmy_lib.dylib, here's the cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(testLib)

set(FIND_LIB_PATH /Users/sean/Projects/custom-library/cmake-build-release/)
message(STATUS FIND_LIB_PATH=${FIND_LIB_PATH})


find_library(MY_LIB
        NAMES libmy_lib      // the file is called libmy_lib.dylib
        PATHS FIND_LIB_PATH)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


add_executable(testLib main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testLib PUBLIC ${MY_LIB})
```

I am getting this error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
```

I know the path is correct and the filename is correct, is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved my question, you have to remove the "lib" prefix from the your .dylib name!